# Сложность алгоритма добавления к строке в цикле

Tags: python, time-complexity

Достаточно распространённая gotcha, что

```
r = ""
for c in s:
  r += c
```

может быть сложностью `O(len(s)**2)` в Python, но так ли это на самом деле, и если да (или нет), то почему?

Comment: сложность явно линейная, http://ideone.com/wqfd8C тут с изменением в 10 раз скорость меняется в 10 раз. Скорее всего квадратичная сложность - если строка неизменяемый объект и её нужно копировать полностью при каждой операции, тут это видимо не так (ну или оптимизатор сработал)

Comment: @pavel "явно линейная": строки в Питоне неизменяемы. Попробуйте к примеру на Jython запустить. Вот [подробное описание от создателя языка](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/). CPython (после 2.5)  **иногда** может оптимизировать (в качестве специального случая) код типа `r +=`. Так как тяжело новичкам объяснять, что всегда следует `''.join` использовать вместо `s+=`. Вот [хороший ответ от Alex Martelli на связанный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1350289/4279).

Comment: @pavel: чтобы осознать хрупкость оптимизации, сравните: `python -mtimeit -s 's="a"*1000000' $'r = ""\nfor c in s:\n r += c'` и `python -mtimeit -s 's="a"*1000000' $'r = ""\nfor c in s:\n r += c\n t=r'`

Comment: @jfs так может в ответ сразу?)

Comment: @pavel для ответа необходимо явно описать почему неизменяемость строк ведёт к квадратичному поведению в доступном виде. Вы похоже понимаете почему это происходит—попробуйте изложить как вы это понимаете в виде ответа.

Comment: @jfs поправьте может чего...

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим этот вопрос в целом для разных языков.

Случай первый. Строки **изменяемые**, строка представляет собой указатель на некий массив (или иную структуру данных) символов (+ возможно обёртка с функциями). Примеры языков - С (char *) и С++ (string).

В этом случае код из вопроса по сути вырождается в обычное добавление элемента в массив. И если это не <strike>низкокачественная лаба</strike> самописная реализация то сложность добавления (аммортизированная) будет не больше чем длина того что добавляется.

Тогда очевидно сложность на 1 итерацию будет O(1) а суммарно O(len).

Плюсы данного подхода - скорость работы (добавление, возможность замены символов, быстрое создание подстрок).
Минусы - нужно быть очень внимательным что и как меняется в строке, особенно в многопоточных реализациях.

И 2 случай - строки **неизменяемые**. Т.е. объект строка создаётся 1 раз и не может прямым или косвенным образом изменять своё состояние. Это характерно например для Java.

В этом случае происходит каждый раз создание временного объекта, в который копируется вся старая строка + то что нужно добавить. Т.е. грубо говоря (псевдокод)

```
@s - string
r[0] = ''
for i =1: i <= s.length(); i++ 
   r[i] = String.gen(r[i-1] , s[i-1]);
```

И мы создаём Len строк, длинной от 0 до Len включительно, несложно заметить что их суммарная длина  будет Len*(Len+1)/2 ~ O(Len^2).

Кстати при отсутствии нормального сборщика мусора (но обычно он есть в таких языках) можно весьма просесть по памяти.

Плюсы и минусы можно сказать обратные, работать проще но медленнее.

Но в каждом таком языке есть механизм которые позволяют создавать подобное не теряя в производительности. Это может быть конструктор строки из коллекции или специальные утилитарные классы (StringBuiled и подобное). Использование их позволяет существенно ускорить процесс и достичь в данном примере асимптотики  O(len).

Умный компилятор, если может доказать эквивалентность кода (а в такой простой ситуации это несложно) может заменить прямую конкатенацию строк на утилитарную, обеспечив выигрыш в скорости. Именно это и произошло в Питоне в примере http://ideone.com/wqfd8C.

Однако полагаться на это опасно. Цитаты из комментариев.

> Попробуйте к примеру на Jython запустить. Вот подробное описание от создателя языка. CPython (после 2.5) иногда может оптимизировать (в качестве специального случая) код типа r +=. Так как тяжело новичкам объяснять, что всегда следует ''.join использовать вместо s+=. Вот хороший ответ от Alex Martelli на связанный вопрос.

(Ссылка на вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1350289/4279)

> чтобы осознать хрупкость оптимизации, сравните: python -mtimeit -s 's="a"*1000000' $'r = ""\nfor c in s:\n r += c' и python -mtimeit -s 's="a"*1000000' $'r = ""\nfor c in s:\n r += c\n t=r'

В этом случае компилятору не хватает "сообразительности" и он реализовывает что написано в "лоб", что значительно медленнее. Поэтому повторюсь, нужно использовать специальные  конструкции языка и упрощать жизнь компилятору.

Comment: Т.е. причина в том, что чем строка длиннее, тем она дольше создается?

Comment: Начало хорошо, но про компилятор—неверно. Дело не в компиляторе, а в реализации **интерпретатора**. В Jython  и даже в Pypy с JIT—это квадратичная операция. Питон код   компилируется в байт-код, который затем **интерпретируется**.   В случае с оптимизацией и без (`t=r`) одна и та же операция `INPLACE_ADD` выполняется—разница только в конкретной реализации для строк: вероятно `+=` замечает, что r это единственная ссылка на строку, поэтому изменения по месту происходят (вместо создания новой строки и выбрасывания существующей). `t=r` создаёт ещё одну ссылку на строку, что выключает оптимизацию.

Comment: Не соображу, если добавляя символ мы будем делать `realloc` удваивая размер буфера (распространенная тактика), то какая будет сложность -- n log n ?

Comment: @avp нет, n. Суммарно за все время будет 2n памяти выделено.

Comment: @jfs правьте) я сразу сказал что только примерно ответ знаю, могу общим сделать чтобы проще было.

Comment: @pavel, я о времени (мы же о нем говорим). Понятно, что в тривиальном тесте (как в примерах)  новая память будет добавляться с хвоста и время тоже будет O(n) / Кстати, такая картина вполне согласуется с Вашими замерами.

Comment: @avp в итоге время О(n)—анализ считает что при каждом выделении памяти приходится копировать все предыдущие элементы (как будто realloc() не используется). Представьте при добавлении k-ого элемента выделили 2*k памяти и скопировали ~k элементов—O(k) операция. Затем для к+1,k+2,...,k+(k-1) ничего выделять не надо—добавление O(1). Итого получаем для всех k элементов стоимость: O(k)+O(1)+O(1)+...+O(1)=O(k). То есть каждый раз приходится вдвое больше копировать, но копирование  вдвое реже происходит и в целом O(n) операция.